# Retrieve of Custom Field having __hd (history trending) files not happening through Metadata API

Tags: metadata-api, custom-field, metadata, workbench

I recently enabled **Tracking History** for 3 fields inside the **Case** object. Even on the workbench in the metadata section of Custom Field, I can see a **Case__hd** folder where all the fields which are set for tracking are shown.
[image: __hd Files]

Now, I am trying to retrieve these __hd files using Metadata API but am not able to retrieve them.
The error says

[image]

The package.xml which I am using for retrieving these files are

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
<types>
    <members>Case__hd.Priority__c</members>
    <members>Case__hd.Status__c</members>
    <members>Case__hd.Reason__c</members>
    <name>CustomField</name>
</types>
<version>34.0</version>
```

Any idea where I am going wrong..!

Answer (score 2):

Those database objects (objects ending with __hd or __history) does not have a specific metadata describing them.

If you want to retrieve this configuration, you need to go to the CustomField

Inside that custom field you have different tags with this information. For example **trackTrending** for historical trending data (__hd) or **trackHistory** for history tracking (__history)

Check the metadata api entry for custom fields for more information https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.234.0.api_meta.meta/api_meta/customfield.htm

and the metadata coverage report https://mdcoverage.secure.force.com/docs/metadata-coverage